# Is there a way to track where the click was performed when listening for clicks with renderer.listenGlobal()?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have this directive which should track clicks in all of the components in the application. To check if there was a click performed is easy; I injected an instance of Renderer and called it's listenGlobal() method and logged a message on the console whenever there was a click. Here is the code;

```
export class TrackerDirective {
    constructor( private _renderer: Renderer) {
        let listener = this._renderer.listenGlobal("document", "click", () =>
            {
                console.log("Clicked...");
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Now the question is; is there a way to track the element (or the component) on which the click was actually performed? I know about using ElementRef and @HostListener() for tracking events but I can't use them. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a parameter to the event handler you'll get the event passed

```
export class TrackerDirective {
    constructor( private _renderer: Renderer) {
        let listener = this._renderer.listenGlobal("document", "click", (event) =>
            {
                console.log(event.screenX, event.screenY, event.clientX, event.clientY);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/click for other values you can get from the click event.